# Flutter return "Widget" from "Future<Widget>"

Tags: flutter

**The problem**

I have a function "stackOverflow" which is shown below. I want that function to return the widget "Icon" but I get the error code: The argument type `Future<Widget>` can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

```
`Future<Widget> stackOverflow () async{
    var value1 = 0;
    var value2 = 7;
    var value3 = 20;
    if (value1 >= 1 && value1 <= 5){
      return Icon(
          Icons.check_circle
      );}
    else if (value2 >= 6 ||value2 <= 8){
      return Icon(
          Icons.ac_unit
      );
    }
  }`
```

**I have tried**

Putting "stackOverflow" in a futurebuilder (full code down below)

Putting "stackOverflow" raw in the widget tree (full code down below)

**The full code (it's minimal because I am focussing on the problem.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {



  Future<Widget> stackOverflow () async{
    var value1 = 0;
    var value2 = 7;
    var value3 = 20;
    if (value1 >= 1 && value1 <= 5){
      return Icon(
          Icons.check_circle
      );}
    else if (value2 >= 6 ||value2 <= 8){
      return Icon(
          Icons.ac_unit
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Is between 1 & 5'),
                stackOverflow()
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Is between 6 & 8'),
                FutureBuilder(
                    future:
                    stackOverflow(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                          return Text('none');
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return Text('waiting');
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          if (snapshot.hasError)
                            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          return stackOverflow();//snapshot.data;
                      // You can reach your snapshot.data['url'] in here
                      }
                      return null; // unreachable
                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Is 20'),

              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've understood the issue correctly. Your attempt to use `FutureBuilder` is right.

**In the first Row:**

```dart
children: <Widget>[
  Text('Is between 1 & 5'),
  FutureBuilder<Widget>(
    future: stackOverflow(),
    initialData: const SizedBox.shrink(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.data;
    },
  ),
],
```

**In the second Row:**

```dart
return stackOverflow();//snapshot.data;
```

has to be

```dart
return snapshot.data;
```